# What are the Hiragana columns called in Japanese?

Tags: words, hiragana

For instance English texts to learn Japanese will refer to ま、み、む、め、も as the Ma column, and I've even seen this terminology used in translations of Japanese material (although I unfortunately couldn't find the original text for these) but I've never seen what the actual words used in Japanese to refer to it are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think it's more typically thought of as a <s>row</s> line of text. See for example [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E8%A1%8C). The <s>row</s> line that contains ま would be called ま行{ぎょう}, where 行{ぎょう} just means a line of text/row/column.

[image]

Comment: Even though 行 usually means (horizonal) row, in the traditional 五十音図 these 行 actually correspond to (vertical) columns, no? See for example the table at [五十音](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E9%9F%B3), and the Meiji era prints in that same wiki article.

Comment: @Will Traditional 五十音図 are in vertical writing, where lines/行 flow vertically. So まみむめも belong to the ま行, and あかさたなはまやらわ belong to the あ段, regardless of the table style.

Comment: @naruto Good point. As you hint at, taking into account that 行 essentially means a line of text (and that its "row" interpretation is only indirectly derived from that) eliminates any horizontal/vertical confusion that might arise when translating things too literally.